# Rails base controller general parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

A have a base controller for my admin namespace

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController

  def update
    entity = @source.find(params[:id])
    close_popup entity.update_attributes(params[@param_name])? {return_url => @url}:{}
  end

  ...

end
```

And all my admin controllers derives from AdminController, eg:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::AdminController
  @source = Admin::Product
  @url = admin_products_url
  @param_name = :admin_product
end
```

Now, my question is how can i avoid setting those parameters in the derrived classes. For that i will need to know from the base controller itself

1. What scaffold is it associeted with. ( @source )
2. The url for listing entities ( @url )
3. Parameter name coming from POST associated to the entity ( @param_name)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are sure that all these controllers will be in the format you mentioned, you could do the following:

define a `before_filter` in the `class Admin::AdminController` named `set_default_parmas`

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_default_params

  def set_default_params
    resource_name = controller_name.singularize
    @source = "Admin::#{resource_name.camelize}".constantize
    @url = self.send("admin_#{controller_name}_url")
    @param_name = "admin_#{resource_name}".to_sym
  end

end
```

references to used methods:
[singularize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-singularize), [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize), [camelize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize) and [controller_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_name/class)

Comment: I edited the answer so that `@url` will have the route you want (used `self.send`).
which line gave you `resource_name undefined` ?